# Unity giving compile error without any error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am learning unity 3d game development and I was following a tutorial and wrote this code for a ball to apply force on its X-axis, but unity said all compile errors must be resolved before going in Playmode:

> code:

```
using System.Numerics;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AddConstantForce : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        GetComponent<RigidBody>().velocity = new Vector3(2,0,0);
    }
}
```

I have update unity version. tried various new sample scenes, and after this error pops it also gives the error with default empty void start and void update functions too.
please help

Comment: Can you provide the compilation error you are getting, that is the key piece of data to understand what is currently wrong with your code

Comment: System.Numerics?

Comment: yes, it was the cause of the error. but the thing that I cant seem to fix is that whenever I use a suggested code completion, these using tags gets added by themselves, I am using vscode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the error information, this is somewhat difficult to debug but I do see two errors with your code.

First, you have a typo on your Update function you are calling `GetComponent<RigidBody>` when the actual name of the class is `Rigidbody` see Unity's documentation for reference https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html

There is also an ambiguous reference between `Vector3` as both `Systems.Numerics` & `UnityEngine` defines that type. you want to stick with the `UnityEngine` definition. so just delete the first line.

So in the end this code should be working without compilation errors

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AddConstantForce : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(2,0,0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, it is a really bad practice to call `GetComponent` on every frame as it can be an expensive operation you can store the rigid body within a variable so you only do that operation once.

Comment: That's what I wrote at the start, I was just messing around with different methods to learn the movement, but vscode kept adding them using Systems. Numerics & UnityEngine, that's what was causing all this fuss and I had to come here because there was no compile error shown in console, I will keep and eye out for this from now on, thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

Try define the getcomponet variable in the void update and then make a new line with the varible first then velocity thing or/and use += insted of =.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).